# PHP: What does this error mean? Abstract method must be compatible?

Tags: php

I have an abstract class. I'm extending that class. I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Default_Model_FoobarMapper::_setClassVarsFromRow() must be compatible with that of Default_Model_AbstractMapper::_setClassVarsFromRow() in /location/to/models/FoobarMapper.php on line 3
```

What does this usually mean?

**Update:** Found out that my type hinting was throwing an error. You can't do this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    abstract protected function _myFunction($array, $generic_class);
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{
    protected function _myFunction($array, Specific_Class $specific_class)
    {
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments you declare for `_setClassVarsFromRow()` must be identical to those in the abstract.

For example, if your abstract says

```
function _setClassVarsFromRow($arg1, $arg2 = null)
```

you can't implement

```
function _setClassVarsFromRow($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null)
```

Comment: does this mean I can't use type hinting?

Comment: You can.  The type hinting just has to be identical on every implementation of the function.

Comment: uh... I think you should be able to, as long as you hint the same types, shouldn't you? I haven't used type hinting in PHP yet so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think Andrew's meaning is this: If the abstract definition (written by somebody else) doesn't use type hinting, does this mean he can't add it to his implementation? And I'm afraid it means what he fears it means. (I just did a quick test.)

Comment: Andrew: To produce a small bit of type safety, you could always just pass the params through to another, type-hinted method, maybe '_setClassVarsFromRow_internal()' or something.

Comment: In some case, if an abstract says: `function ($arg1, $arg2)` you can't implement `function($arg1, $arg2 = null)` event if the arguments count is the same.